# "New Blender Instance" option is missing the "Edit Linked Library" addon

Tags: scripting, add-on, linked-data

"Edit Linked Library" is a built in addon that allows me to open the linked object in it's original file. However I want to open it in a new instance of Blender. This is supposedly a function, as per this video from 2013: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJm_kDgQUv0&ab_channel=CGCookie

Does anyone know why it's missing 2.90 + ?

[image: missing option]

Comment: I've never used it, but it seems to be available in the addons list in Blender 2.93. Just type 'lib' into the search field under Preferences > Addons and it shows up as 'Object: Edit Linked Library'. Enable it and its entry then appears under File > External Data > Edit Linked Library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this wasn't my question. I can use the addon fine, and it opens the linked file, but I want it to open in a new instance, which isn't an option.

Comment: That option isn't mentioned at all in the official [2.93 description](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/addons/object/edit_linked_library.html) for that addon so maybe it was removed for some reason?

Comment: Yeah maybe. I can see it in the .py code though. I tried to manually change it to true instead of false, but didn't change anything. So maybe there's some functionality missing for it to work in 2.90